# Authenticate local user without running as root

Tags: c, authentication

A server applicaton I wrote is running as root at the moment and authenticates local system users with getspnam() and crypt() which requires root privilege to access the shadow file. Now I want that application not to run as root in a production system. What are the alternatives without ever requiring root for authenticating local users? The application is running under debian at the moment but is written portable in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those files you read are supposed to be read by a userspace application. They are system files. The administrator is free to leave the files in place but inhibit their contents - a perfectly valid scenario - and there may well be user information that goes beyond what's in those files. Say, if the machine is joined to an Active Directory domain, or otherwise uses LDAP for authentication: the user list will come from the directory, with `passwd` having just the local system accounts and nothing else. System services need those files in `/etc`, and that's that - specifically, the PAM module that provides local accounts :)

Thus: use Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM). You'll be using the [public interface to PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-interface.html). Since PAM is cross-platform, it will work on other unices, [say Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-2145/pam-1.html).